# Spring API gateway dynamic uri in routes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api-gateway

I have a few services with following urls:
s1.mydomain.com
s2.mydomain.com
...
In addition I have and API gateway on api.mydomain.com

I want following behaviour
request api.mydomain.com/s1/bla will be forwarded to s1.mydomain.com/bla
request api.mydomain.com/s2/bla will be forwarded to s2.mydomain.com/bla
etc

I can configure miltiple routes on api gateway, with RewritePath, however I want to configure single rule that follows convention. Somethinkg like

`routes: - id: dynamic_route uri: https://{service_name}.mydomain.com predicates: - Path=*/bla/** filters: - RewritePath=/bla/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}`

Currently I'm unable to use a pattern in uri inside routes.
How can I get sycj generic routing?

Thanks